# Need proper syntax using EF6 Fluent API between 2 tables using PK and FK

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-key-relationship

If you all need more details I will send them for sure. Here is a screen shot containing 2 tables:

[image]

Basically this is what looks like in SQL today:

[image]

I am trying to use the fluent API for the relationship but not sure how to do it.
Table 1 has a PK and a FK.
Table 2 does not have a PK, only FK.
Below is an example of what I need but this code applies to a different set of tables. I am trying to get the "relationship" syntax correct for the scenario described here:

```
    this.ToTable("Server");
    //primary key
    this.HasKey(t => t.serverId);
    //properties
    ...
    //relationships
    this.HasMany(n => n.NetworkAdapters)
        .WithRequired(s => s.Server)
        .HasForeignKey(s => s.serverId)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Thank you

Comment: Does Table 2 have anything that identifies a row uniquely? Otherwise EF won't be able to manage it.

Comment: hi Gert, no it does not. I ended up adding a PK to table 2 and did a 1 to many relationship just like the one I demo here. How do I close this question? or answer it so people wont try to reply to it anymore.thanks

Comment: how do I vode for deletion? click on down arrow? make -1?

Answer (score 0):

Without the primary key on table 2 you are most likely looking for a One-to–Zero-or-One relationship. You might possibly be requiring both ends which I will describe too.

**One-to–Zero-or-One**

```
// Configure the primary key for Table1
   modelBuilder.Entity<Table1>()
    .HasKey(t => t.networkAdapterId);

// Map one-to-zero or one relationship
   modelBuilder.Entity<Table2>()
    .HasRequired(t => t.Table1)
    .WithOptional(t => t.Table2);
```

**One-to-One**

```
// Configure the primary key for the Table1
   modelBuilder.Entity<Table1>()
    .HasKey(t => t.networkAdapterId);

// Map one-to-one relationship
   modelBuilder.Entity<Table2>()
    .HasRequired(t => t.Table1)
    .WithRequiredPrincipal(t => t.Table2);
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj591620.aspx#RequiredToRequired) for more details

Comment: Actually in this scenario Table 2 can have more than 1 row, that is, it can have for instance 3 rows (3 ipAddresses) containing the same FK which points to the networkAdapter in Table 1. This is the way it is configured in our SQL environment and that is why I was confused. This looks more like a 1 to MANY to me but Table 2 has no PK! :(

Comment: Then table2's primary key is networkAdapterId and ipAddress? You would need to set it as follows: modelBuilder.Entity<Table2>().HasKey(o => new { o.networkAdapterId, o.ipAddress });  Then you should be able to set your one-to-many relationship as above. Let me know if this is the solution and I will write up a new answer.

Comment: Table 2 has no PK whatsoever. I have added another screen shot. Let me know if that helps to explain my scenario please.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm afraid I'm not sure then. I can't imagine a one-to-many relationship can exist in such a scenario where the child table rows cannot be uniquely identified via a PK.